# Can a create a directory on a remote cluster in hadoop by doing a -mkdir?

Tags: hadoop, mkdir, hadoop-partitioning

We are moving data inter cluster on a partition by partition basis and we have a requirement to use 
-update -skipcrccheck option only for this. In order to run distcp on a partition by partition basis with these options requires partition directory to be already created at the destination. In order to do that I need to perform -mkdir from a remote cluster on the destination cluster.

I tried to google for an answer but couldn't find anything. Is that something which is possible?

Comment: Are you looking for solution where source directories will be created in target without explicitly creating directories in target hadoop cluster? question in title is not clear.

Comment: that is correct Ajay_SK. My current distcp command is: hadoop distcp -f <Source file paths on cluster A> -m 1 -pbt -skipcrccheck -update <hdfs cluster B>

Answer (score 0):

When DistCp is invoked without -update or -overwrite, the DistCp defaults would create directories first/ and second/, under /target.

```
distcp -skipcrccheck  hdfs://nn1:8020/source/first hdfs://nn1:8020/source/second hdfs://nn2:8020/target
```

Output:

```
hdfs://nn2:8020/target/first/1
hdfs://nn2:8020/target/first/2
hdfs://nn2:8020/target/second/10
hdfs://nn2:8020/target/second/20
```